# Removed posts that are on topic

Tags: discussion

If my posts keep getting deleted, can I get the incorrect information regarding no safety when indeed there was, deleted and my photo removed.

[How to tandem rappel/abseil with a child?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7982/how-to-tandem-rappel-abseil-with-a-child)

Comment: "my posts keep getting deleted" how many posts are we talking about, here?

Comment: One has been reinstated, but the more important one regarding correct tandem abseil procedure is still missing.

Answer (score 6):

I was responsible for the delete.  I think Rory's solution of "convert to comment was a better one" and I should have done that.

As far as "why"

1. The flag reason was legit - Ie, they should have been comments, not answers.
2. They were from two separate accounts which is, in and of itself, suspicious activity.
3. We actually have no simple way to know that you are the "you" in the picture.  It could be any guy claiming anything about the guy in the picture.

While #3 may seem weird, falsely claiming to be "the person in question" is not terribly uncommon on the internet.

Comment: New users can't comment and that's a common problem that they will use an answer. #3, erm maybe but I think that is pulling hairs. John is going trough a lot of trouble to learn a website rules and being pretty polite about it. If we use his picture, I hope we'll fulfill his request or simply edit and not use the picture.

Comment: "New users can't comment and that's a common problem that they will use an answer." -- Not a lot we can do about that one.  Those rules apply to all of SO as far as I know.  

Regarding simply editing, Rory has already added the commentary and updates into the post, and had done so prior to the time at which I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 6):

These are the posts you were referring to:

[image]

As the others have already mentioned, they did not serve well as answers, but did serve well as comments. I entertained them as comments because I noticed you didn't have enough reputation, but the proper thing would have been to flag them so one of the moderators could convert them to comments.

Answer (score 4):

I found your posts, finally (was tricky as they were from two separate accounts), and I see the reason they were deleted was that they were left as answer posts but were really just comments on another post.

I have undeleted one and moved it to a comment, and added the content of the other into Liam's answer.

Once you have earned more rep here you will be able to add comments yourself, but until you do, please don't use answer posts for comments. That isn't how Stack Exchange works.

Please read our help pages for guidance.

Comment: Hi, I corrected some incorrect information I.e. that there was a safety line in the picture, it's just hard to see. If it helps, it was James James? that deleted it.

Comment: Okay - one of us mods can add that in. And as soon as you have a wee bit of rep you'll be able to as well. So that's you in the picture? Cool

Comment: I found it - looks like you were in as a different user

Comment: Thank you for that, it's much appreciated.